# ECLIPSE C/C++ : Retrieving entire header file flow

Tags: eclipse, search, header-files

Eclipse Version:
     Version: 4.3.2
     Build id: M20140221-1700

To keep it simple, lets say I have 3 header files.

Header file 1 (header1.h) has the following :

```
  #define LIMIT 10
```

Header file 2 (header2.h)

```
 #include header1.h
```

Header file 3  (header3.h)

```
 #include header2.h
```

The actual code contains the following :

```
 #include header3.h
```

In the C code, LIMIT is referenced and if I press "CTRL+Mouse click" it takes me directly to header1.h.

Is there a command that will allow me to click LIMIT in my code and it return something like the following :

header3.h -> header2.h ->  header1.h

or any format?

Answer (score 0):

Right click anywhere in the file editor where the "actual code" is open

Then in the context menu, click: show in -> Include Browser.

At first it will show files including the current source file.
There is an icon at the top of the Include Browser that will switch it to show the tree of included files.

Comment: I don't see a "Include Browser". Instead there are these options "History", "Project Explorer", "Outline", "Navigator", "Properties". The "Outline" seems to show what you mention by listing all the header files in this file, but there is no icon to switch to the tree of included files. Possibly a difference in Versions???

Comment: @UnhandledException Since you were talking about C develeopment I was assuming you have CDT included in your eclipse install. The "Include Browser" is included with that.